# Shunting Yard Algorithm and perentheses not providing correct output

Tags: c#, algorithm, stack

I'm attempting to create a calculator that allows for PEMDAS Calculation. The issue I'm running into is when I'm attempting to run 5x2+(5x10)/5 it returns 52. This is actually the answer to 5x2/5 = 2 + (5x10) = 52. I'm using The Shunting Yard Algorithm to implement PEMDAS Functionality.

If I understand stacks correctly, then it appears that it's calculating (5x10) = 50 first (as it should), but then calculates the other operands separate from the (5x10) and then finally add the 2 together. When I'm wanting to calculate all of them at once according to PEMDAS rules.

[image: What I think my code is doing vs what I want it to do]

This is my Evaluate Function

```
public double evaluate(string expression)
    {
        Stack<double> operandStack = new Stack<double>();
        Stack<char> operatorStack = new Stack<char>();
        Queue<string> outputQueue = new Queue<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < expression.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = expression[i];

            if (char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.')
            {
                string operand = "";
                while (i < expression.Length && (char.IsDigit(expression[i]) || expression[i] == '.'))
                {
                    operand += expression[i];
                    i++;
                }
                outputQueue.Enqueue(operand);
                i--;
            }
            else if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '%' || c == '^')
            {
                while (operatorStack.Count > 0 && HasHigherPrecedence(c, operatorStack.Peek()))
                {
                    outputQueue.Enqueue(operatorStack.Pop().ToString());
                }
                operatorStack.Push(c);
            }
            else if (c == '(')
            {
                string subExpression = "";
                int parenthesesCount = 1;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < expression.Length; j++)
                {
                    char subChar = expression[j];
                    if (subChar == '(')
                    {
                        parenthesesCount++;
                    }
                    else if (subChar == ')')
                    {
                        parenthesesCount--;
                    }
                    if (parenthesesCount == 0)
                    {
                        subExpression = expression.Substring(i + 1, j - i - 1);
                        i = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                double subResult = evaluate(subExpression);
                outputQueue.Enqueue(subResult.ToString());
            }
        }

        while (operatorStack.Count > 0)
        {
            outputQueue.Enqueue(operatorStack.Pop().ToString());
        }

        while (outputQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            string item = outputQueue.Dequeue();
            if (double.TryParse(item, out double operand))
            {
                operandStack.Push(operand);
            }
            else
            {
                if (operandStack.Count < 2)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Not enough operands on the stack.");
                }
                double operand2 = operandStack.Pop();
                double operand1 = operandStack.Pop();

                switch (item)
                {
                    case "+":
                        operandStack.Push(operand1 + operand2);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        operandStack.Push(operand1 - operand2);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        operandStack.Push(operand1 * operand2);
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        operandStack.Push(operand1 / operand2);
                        break;
                    case "%":
                        operandStack.Push(operand1 % operand2);
                        break;
                    case "^":
                        operandStack.Push(Math.Pow(operand1, operand2));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return operandStack.Pop();
    }
```

This is my parentheses precedence bool.

```
 private bool HasHigherPrecedence(char currentOperator, char stackOperator)
    {
        if (stackOperator == '(' || stackOperator == ')')
        {
            return false;
        }
        if ((currentOperator == '*' || currentOperator == '/' || currentOperator == '%') && (stackOperator == '+' || stackOperator == '-'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if ((currentOperator == '^') && (stackOperator != '^'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (currentOperator == '+' || currentOperator == '-')
        {
            if (stackOperator == '+' || stackOperator == '-')
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I've attempted to resolve this by destroying the initial stack, then remaking the stack with the answer of the parentheses in place of the parentheses. This came up with stranger answers, I might not have implemented it correctly, but at this point, Occams razor hasn't helped.
I've also tried to separate it into 2 evaluate doubles, one for parentheses only, then the other putting the parentheses answer in place of the parentheses. This did sort of work, but at random, I'd get an empty stack error, even when running the same calculation.

I need guidance as to how to implement parentheses answers properly.

Comment: You should probably chose your debugging examples more carefully. Or start with smaller examples. Suppose parentheses are working fine but you have the precedence test backwards, so that addtion binds more tightly than multiplication. Then `5*2+50/5` would evaluate as `5*(2+50)/5`, which is 52. You don't have to imagine some bug which reorders the stack. If you're trying to do precedence parsing, your best first test cases would be something like `1+2*3` and `3*2+1`. If those are both 7, cool. If they're both 9, your precedence check is inverted. Otherwise, different problem.

Comment: Also, Occam's razor called to ask what the point of the Output Queue is? Why don't you just compute the value as you go without an additional unnecessary enqueue and later dequeue?

Comment: @rici One of the oddities I've noticed is that computer science courses will often teach how to evaluate a postfix string, and they'll teach how to turn an infix expression into a postfix string. But for some reason they don't teach that if you can parse an infix expression to a postfix string, then you can just evaluate it as you go along. So we have legions of Comp Sci graduates who think that the way to handle infix expressions is to first convert it to postfix (or prefix) and then evaluate.

Comment: @JimMischel: Indeed. I've complained about that many times. Unfortunately, the international cabal of CS educators don't generally take my advice. (FWIW, I think it's because a lot of these courses are still delivered in C, a language in which creating an AST is dominated by housekeeping details. Creating a postfix string -- not even a dynamic list of tokens -- may seem "easier to teach". Personally, I think that ASTs and codegen should be taught *before* parsing, because knowing what you're going to do with the parse makes it easier to produce an appropriate data stream.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching this problem the wrong way. What it looks like you're doing is parsing the string, pushing operands onto the operand stack, and using an operator stack as an interim mechanism to order the operators into the output queue. Then you go through some method of merging the operator queue with the operand stack to produce your final output. I suppose you could make that work, but it's rather convoluted. It might *resemble* the Shunting Yard Algorithm, but only slightly.

The Wikipedia article for the Shunting Yard Algorithm has a very good section called [The algorithm in detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_detail) that explains it very well. If you study that algorithm you'll see that it outputs as it goes along. That is, where in your code you send an operator to the output queue, the actual Shunting Yard algorithm pops operands from the operand stack, evaluates that part of the expression, and pushes the result back onto the operand stack. So, for example, rather than sending `'+'` to the output queue to be evaluated later, it pops the two operands, performs the addition, and then pushes the result back onto the operand stack.

That article also shows you how to handle parentheses in a straightforward way rather than the convoluted special case looping construct that you created. Basically, when it encounters an opening paren, the code pushes that onto the operator stack. When it encounters a closing paren, the code starts popping operators and operands, performing evaluations and pushing the result back onto the operand stack. It continues doing that until the operator it pops is an opening paren. (Or until it clears the stack, which indicates an error because there was no opening paren.)

My advice to you is to study closely that section about the algorithm in detail. Get out a pencil and a piece of paper and do some simple exercises, going character-by-character through an expression, "pushing" and "popping" your stacks on paper until you have a good understanding of how the thing works. Then sit down and write your code to do *exactly* that.